# Can't install Dynamics CRM in VS 2012 for Windows 10

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-365

I have windows 10 machine and VS 2012 installed. I am trying to install 'Microsoft Dynamics 365 Software Development Kit (SDK)'(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50032) on my machine.

I extracted the installer. But I didn't see the Developer Toolkit in the 'Tools' folder. I checked in the VS 2012 it didn't installed.

Anyone have idea how to install this for windows 10.

Please see below screen-shot:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rEVd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avail the **developer toolkit** in Visual Studio, follow the below steps:

1. Install [Microsoft Dynamics 365 Software Development Kit (SDK)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50032)
2. Install [Microsoft Dynamics 365 Developer Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DynamicsCRMPG.MicrosoftDynamicsCRMDeveloperToolkit)